# How to properly load values of a full dataset of variables from a file?

Tags: c++, variables, loading

Hi stackoverflow community,

I have currently a dataset of constants in my code which is loaded from a text file. Those variables are used all the times in a learning algorithm so I declared them as member of my class for execution speed (example below with 6 but I have 100+ of them) :

```cpp
class learningGraphDataset
{
public:
   learningGraphDataset();
   loadDatasetValuesFromTextFile();

private:
    // DATASET
    uint32_t _CST_FACTOR_MIN1;
    uint32_t _CST_FACTOR_MIN2; 
    uint32_t _CST_FACTOR_MAX12;
    uint32_t _CST_FACTOR_MAX12;
    **
    ** (many others)
    **
    uint32_t _CST_LIMIT13;
};
```

I keep all the values in a file to be able to generate a new set of data (genetic algorithm), and restart the soft with the new dataset text file.

The problem is when I want to load each values from the text file, I have something like 800 lines of :

```cpp
QString cstName = tmpLineSplitted[0];
uint32_t cstVal = tmpLineSplitted[1].toUInt();
if (cstName == "CST_FACTOR_MIN1_VAL") 
{
     _CST_FACTOR_MIN1 = cstVal;
     errorOnLine=false;
     nbConstantsLoaded++;
}
else if (cstName == "CST_FACTOR_MIN2_VAL") 
{
     _CST_FACTOR_MIN2 = cstVal;
     errorOnLine=false;
     nbConstantsLoaded++;
}
**
**(many others)
**
else if (cstName == "CST_LIMIT13_VAL") 
{
     _CST_LIMIT13 = cstVal;
     errorOnLine=false;
     nbConstantsLoaded++;
}
```

And to add one more constant it begin to be quite slow.
My text file look like this :

```cpp
CST_FACTOR_MIN1_VAL;61;
CST_FACTOR_MIN2_VAL;13;
**
**(many others)
**
CST_LIMIT13_VAL;27;
```

I know that in C++ there is no way to load a variable like this ("reflective" language?)

```cpp
variable("_CST_FACTOR_MIN1") = cstVal;
```

The code works but is there a way to write all this in a nicer way? Mapping maybe? With everything on two column maybe (var name in text file & real var name)? If a could load all the constants with a loop that would help to get a more clear code.

I use C++11 & the Qt5 lib

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question probably fits better for [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Why not simplyfy the whole thing and rather represent you dataset(s) as a map of `std::map<QString,uint32_t>`?

Comment: Probably the best solution but how do I call a variable after that?
If I write myMap("_CST_FACTOR_MIN1") I suppose the mapper will take a lot of time to find my variable? In a for(;;) loop I think I will just kill the performances...

Comment: You can use the map as an internal representation of `learningGraphDataset`.

Comment: Could you give me more details please? I'm not sure to understand